# Proper use of a switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm wondering how to use the switch statement, and I have a couple questions.

1. What is the `case '':` for? as in, how do I set the conditions?
2. How many cases can I have?

Comment: Does [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) (scroll down to the section on switch statements) help?

Comment: Great tutorials for this exist in the hundreds. How hard did you look for one before asking about it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set the conditions?

It's very simple: assuming an integral type `Type` you can use:

```
Type i;
switch (i) {
case x:
    // ...
    break;
case y:
    // ...
    break;
// ...
default:
    // ...
    break; // optional
};
```

where `x`, `y`, ... etc. are values convertible to the integral type `Type` that you want to check for *equality* in `i`.

So for example:

```
int x = 3;
switch (x) {
case 1:
    std::cout << '1';
    break;
case 2:
    std::cout << '2';
    break;
case 3:
    std::cout << '3';
    break;
default: break;
};
```

would print:

> 3

For more detailed informations on the *switch statement*, please visit [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch).

---

> How many cases can i have?

As many as you want.

Comment: Can you have as many as you want, or as many as the integral type in the `switch` supports? I mean, if you switch on a `unsigned char` and have 300 cases, there must be 44 duplicates. My guess is that, while you can write this *syntactically*, semantically the behavior must either be “first wins”, “last wins” or undefined. I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but saying you can have as many as you like is probably not strictly accurate or at least not the whole story.

Comment: Thanks! so I have to have an integer value for my switch? that's pretty simple! this is gonna work wonders!

Comment: @Trevader24135, an integral type, this includes `int`, `unsigned`, ..., and `char`s.

Comment: Oh, whats the I and how do I use it?

Comment: @Trevader24135, what's the what?

Comment: @Jeffery in the examples above, he uses I, whats the I?

Comment: @Trevader24135: A typo that I've just fixed.